# Populate extra values from second column

Tags: excel, formula

I have two column: A and B. I want to check each value of column A as to if it exists in B. If it doesn't, I want to add a new row with the value.

Answer (score 0):

something like this will return a number of the start position if the term exists

```
  =FIND("some text","some cell text with some text")
```

you can then wrap this in an if

```
 =if(FIND("some text","some cell text with some text")>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

if you true you'll need to add a new row

if false you will not.

adding a new row is difficult if you have several rows already, do you want the row inserted, or added to the bottom of a list etc..

it would be easier to do a filter on the 'true' column and copy and paste these as a new row and edit to suit.